# How to cast/convert a browser FormData object to a Dart object, in Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart2js

Basically I have a `FormData` object on the Javascript side in Flutter Web.

I need to send this object to Dart in order to make a http POST request, having the object's fields (including some eventual **Blob/File** field, as well) as the payload. The way I send this object to Dart is by registering a callback in Dart on the `js.context` window object, and calling that from the Javascript side.

Now, I've tried many different ways to achieve this:

- Get all it's fields using the spread operator, `[...formData]`
- `JSON.stringify` it and send it as a String
- `JSON.stringify` it's `.entries()`
- `JSON.stringify` it's `keys()` and `values()` individually
- some other work-arounds I found on the internet

I was able to send `FormData`'s "simple" fields (String, number, Array, Object) **BUT NOT FILE/BLOBs** using theese approaches.

Is there any way to get that `FormData` object as a whole? That is, including the Files/Blobs it might contain, if any.

Thanks